# text-overflow: elipsis for non text elements

Tags: css

```
 <div className="parent">
      <div className="child">
        <div class="innerChild">
          <span>here some text /</span>
        </div>
        <div class="innerChild">
          <span>heres much more text  /</span>
        </div>
        <div class="innerChild">
          <span>heres the most amount of text </span>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

How to make `.parent` show `...` in the end when it's being overflown ?

So the outcome would look like: `heres some text / heres much more text / heres the most amount....`

```
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

This doesn't work!

Comment: What do the slashes represent in your desired output?

Comment: If that is supposed to be HTML, then all those `className` attributes would need to be just `class`. (And if it is supposed to be something else, something pre-processed or similar, then please tag appropriately.)

Answer (score -1):

Just give the same style to `.innerChild` instead of `.parent` and it will work.

The CSS rules need to be applied to the children rather than the parent, because that's where the actual text content is.

```css
.innerChild {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="innerChild">
      <span>here some text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="innerChild">
      <span>heres much more text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="innerChild">
      <span>heres the most amount of text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```